# function that call itself in vba

Tags: vba

this is the code that I got at the end with the help of Latch, this would be an easy example of a subrutine that changes values in global collection in a recursive way, and now is completly funtional

```
Public List_of_data As New Collection

Sub main()

ClearCollection List_of_data

List_of_data.Add 7.5

List_of_data.Add 1

Recursive_function List_of_data

End Sub

Public Sub ClearCollection(parmCol As Collection)

Set parmCol = New Collection

End Sub

Public Function Recursive_function(ByRef List_of_data As Collection)

Dim x1

x1 = List_of_data.Item(1)

Dim x2

x2 = List_of_data.Item(2)

If x1 > x2 Then

ClearCollection List_of_data

List_of_data.Add x1

List_of_data.Add x2 + 1

Call Recursive_function(List_of_data)

End If

End Function
```

Comment: If a function calls itself, it will never end. Think of a 12 step program. If step 11 was "go to step 1 of a 12 step program", would you ever complete the first program you started?

Comment: The concept of calling oneself is called *recursion*, and it's very commonly found in functional languages and shouldn't be used with global variables.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon : only if the call is unconditional. which it's not here as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ah, Miguel, by the way: add a tag to your question specifying which version of VBA you're using!

Comment: And another hint: it's more likely that more people will read your source code if it's in English.

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ Yes, I see you are correct. My apologies.

Comment: off topic: why the clearcollection function, if the collection has a method clear? like instead of "ClearCollection lista_de_datos" just put lista_de_datos.clear

Comment: helpful for vba error: in which line does the error occur if you press "Debug"?

Comment: @MarcusMüller also im using the vba version thats comes along with the Solidworks 2014 macro editor, which will be Microsoft Visual Basic for aplications 7.1

Comment: @pony2deer, i tried the .clear method at first but got an error, after seeing that there was no Clear option in the little window that appear after you write the ".", I diceded to make my own clear function using the remove command that was listed, also the debug occurs at the End Function line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an argument to a function that takes none. Changing your function to:

```
Public Function Calculo_de_Dientes_Epicicloidales(byref lista_de_datos)
```

will yeild the result you are looking for.

Also, instead of looping to empty your collection, you could simply do:

```
Public Sub ClearCollection(parmCol As Collection)

    set parmCol = new collection

End Sub
```

Comment: I made the change that you suggested in ClearCollection, and it works as a charm, Sadly the byref lista_datos made a conflict with the other sub rutines, i will edit the original code as how i have it now

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to translate x2 = lista_de_datos, so if you have in your code too, this will cause an error. You should also change set paramCol (see edit on my post), that was an error on my part.

Comment: ok, i translated also the "lista_de_datos", and made the set in the clearcollection, but now i get an compile error that says "ByRef argument type mismatch"

Comment: You can either add "as collection" after the byref List_of_data or simply not use the clearcollection function and put set List_of_data = new collection in your code where the function call was.

Comment: I stated the line like this: "Public Function Recursive_function(ByRef List_of_data As Collection)" , and just as you said now it works!! thx a lot i will edit the code as how i have it now without error, and with this example i think I will be able to complete the more complex one that i was trying to achive before

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "call" a function. A function provides a result; you need to set some variable equal to your function. If you just need the code to run, and don't need it to provide you with a specific variable result, then make it a sub, and not a function.

Also, do you have "End Function" below the last line you have copied for us?

Comment: `You cannot "call" a function` - I think that may be overstating it: you can use `Call` when running a function and it will not error.